# How can I get the MATLAB source code of the Canny algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

How can I get the source code of the Canny algorithm as [used by MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/images/ref/edge.html), it is fast and accurate. I want the source code because I want to implement it on hardware.

Comment: something like this? [ http://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sastry/ee20/cacode.html ]

Answer (score 3):

About the implementing it on hardware part, I would strongly advice you consult with a lawyer first. That being said, invoking

> edit edge.m

from MATLAB gets you the source code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't always get the source code for MATLAB functions (some you can, some you can't). But a quick Google search for the Canny algorithm in MATLAB returns a number of implementations. For example, there is one on MathWorks [File Exchange site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5529-canny-edge-detection). Is this what you need?

Comment: no, I know how to implement canny but i need it in a very modified way, matlab did it, and i need matlab source code for canny algorithm.